# How to make List in python dataclass that can accept multiple different types?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating new data class in python.

```
@dataclass
class User(Mixin):
  id: int = None
  items: List[DefaultItem] = None
```

This `items` is array of `DefaultItem` objects but I need this to be multiple possible objects like:

```
items: List[DefaultItem OR SomeSpecificItem OR SomeOtherItem] = None
```

How can I do something like this in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) for this.

```
items: List[Union[DefaultItem, SomeSpecificItem, SomeOtherItem]] = None
```

And if you are on Python 3.10, they've added a convenient shorthand notation:

```
items: list[DefaultItem | SomeSpecificItem | SomeOtherItem] = None
```

Also just as a note: If `items` is allowed to be `None`, you should mark the type as [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional).

Answer (score 2):

Also, a note that in Python 3.10, you can also pass the `kw_only` parameter to the `@dataclass` decorator to work around the issue which I suspect you're having, wherein all fields in a subclass are required to have a default value when there is at least one field with a default value in the superclass, `Mixin` in this case.

I added an example below to illustrate this a little better:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Mixin:
    string: str
    integer: int = 222


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class User(Mixin):
    id: int
    items: list['A | B | C']


class A: ...
class B: ...
class C: ...


u = User(string='abc', id=321, integer=123, items=[])
print(u)
```

Note that I've also wrapped the `Union` arguments in a string, so that the expression is *forward-declared* (i.e. not evaluated yet), since the classes in the `Union` arguments are defined a bit later.

This code works in 3.10 because the `kw_only` param is enabled, so now only keyword arguments are accepted to the constructor. This allows you to work around that issue as mentioned, where you would otherwise need to define a default value for all fields in a subclass when there's at least one default field in a parent class.

In earlier Python versions than 3.10, missing the `kw_only` argument, you'd expect to run into a `TypeError` as below:

```
TypeError: non-default argument 'id' follows default argument
```

The workaround for this in a pre-3.10 scenario is exactly how you had it: define a default value for all fields in the `User` class as below.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Mixin:
    string: str
    integer: int = 222


@dataclass
class User(Mixin):
    id: int = None
    items: list[A | B | C] = field(default_factory=list)


class A: ...
class B: ...
class C: ...


u = User('abc', 123, 321)
print(u)
```